# Codewars challenge solution is too slow

Tags: python-3.x

The challenge is like so:

Your task is to construct a building which will be a pile of n cubes. The cube at the bottom will have a volume of n3 n^3 n3, the cube above will have volume of (n−1)3 (n-1)^3 (n−1)3 and so on until the top which will have a volume of 13 1^3 13.

You are given the total volume m of the building. Being given m can you find the number n of cubes you will have to build?

The parameter of the function findNb (find_nb, find-nb, findNb, ...) will be an integer m and you have to return the integer n such as n3+(n−1)3+(n−2)3+...+13=m n^3 + (n-1)^3 + (n-2)^3 + ... + 1^3 = m n3+(n−1)3+(n−2)3+...+13=m if such a n exists or -1 if there is no such n.
Examples:

findNb(1071225) --> 45

findNb(91716553919377) --> -1

I have solved as follows, but its too slow. Is there a way to make it faster?

```
def find_nb(m):
    n = 0
    x = 0
    while x < m:
        n += 1
        x = sum([(n-i)**3 for i in range(n)])
        if x == m:
            return n
        else:
            continue
    return -1

print(find_nb(135440716410000))
```

Comment: Instead of performing a separate sum of cubes for each `x`, compute a single *running* sum of cubes, starting from 1, and stop when that equals or exceeds `m`.  If it equals `m` then return the corresponding number.  If it exceeds `m` then return -1.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You can use this by python:

```
def findNb(m):
  n = 0
  while m &gt; 0:
      n += 1
      m -= n**3
  return n if m == 0 else -1
```